# .NET Core WebAPI permanent token authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been looking at tutorial after tutorial about securing your .NET Core WebAPI with authentication tokens and everything seems to require a username/password combo in order to get a temporary token for use to authenticate against API controllers.

The project I am working on is using Windows IOT devices running a custom UWP application I wrote that needs to connect to this API in the background in order to record data and pull down the latest device configurations.

I had planned on giving each device a unique token for authenticating that will be entered and stored during the initial device/app setup. Most third party APIs I have worked with just issue you a permanent token that you can use to access their APIs. I was wanting to do something similar.

Comment: In OAuth/OpenID it's called "[client credential flow/grant](https://www.google.com/search?q=ASP.NET%20Core%20Client%20credential%20flow)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JWT seemed overkill and overly complex for my purposes so I ended up going with a middleware solution by following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0llyujNGw8

I ended up creating a middleware class with the following code:

```
public class TokenValidationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TokenValidationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        bool validToken = false;

        //Require HTTPS
        if (context.Request.IsHttps)
        {
            //Skip token authentication for test controller
            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/values"))
            {
                validToken = true;
            }

            //Token header exists in the request
            if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Token"))
            {
                //Check for a valid device by API token in my DB and set validToken to true if found
                if (repository.FindDeviceByAPIKey())
                {
                    validToken = true;
                }
            }

            if (!validToken)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid Token");
            }
            else
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.HttpVersionNotSupported;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("HTTP not supported");
        }
    }
}

public static class TokenExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseTokenAuth(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<TokenValidationMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Then I just added app.UseTokenAuth(); to my Startup class

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard JWT approach, creating two tokens on username/password login.

First token (Access token) is short-lived and contains privileges to access your business login endpoints. The second one (Refresh token) is permanent and allows you to acquire a new Access token, once it has expired, creating a continuous access pattern. Refresh token should only carry a *refresh* claim, which would allow you to access the endpoint used specifically for creating a new short lived token.

Tons of tutorials out there, like http://piotrgankiewicz.com/2017/12/07/jwt-refresh-tokens-and-net-core/